# Why only 48 Stars?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

At the beginning of Daredevil S2E7 - *Semper Fidelis*, why are there 48 stars on the US flag behind Frank Castle as he enters the courtroom? Is this something which is specific to New York? Or is this some kind of statement?

[image]

Comment: Probably due to historical value. Courts are weird. Most of the courts Ive seen use the gold fringe "maritime" flag, not the US flag as defined in the US Flag Code. Seen in the NY Superior court of appeals https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/New_York_Court_of_Appeals_hearing_oral_arguments.jpg and http://www.nycourts.gov/courts/1jd/supctmanh/Moulton.jpg

Comment: Funny enough, every picture I can find of NYC courtroom interiors have the flags on poles, hanging down, not mounted on a wall.

Comment: They used a similar flag in Agents of SHIELD - http://i.imgur.com/H9Q1lBh.png

Comment: I looked around on the internet and see this question has been asked elsewhere. There is a lot of conjecture, but no clear answer as to why. Seeing as how what @Richard has pointed out, I can only imagine there has to be a Marvel reason for this and in doing so, means this is some sort of statement and not just random. This really has me intrigued now.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Actually I think it's because they recycled the prop from Agents of SHIELD. I think its supposed to be a period piece.

Comment: @Richard - When I think of "recycled prop" I think of it as using the same piece of property over again ... the flag in your picture and the flag in the courtroom are of two different sizes, the one in the courtroom appearing almost twice the size of the one in AoS. I don't think in this case the prop was recycled. Even if it was, what is the reason for doing so? The US hasn't had 48 stars since 1959 when Alaska and Hawaii became states ... I'm thinking Daredevil is set in modern day, not the late 50's ... unless I've totally missed something.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Yes, but courts (and old military bases) are often filled with old crap

Comment: @cde The fringe on the flag is just an optimal accessory, often used in indoor and parade flags, as is the finale on the staff which can be a ball, a spearhead, an  eagle, etc.  And I don't know what you mean by "maritime" flags since flags used a sea don't have fringes.

Answer (score 9):

Note how the flag is displayed; fully extended on the wall.  This tells me the flag is not "current" to the episode, as it is actually US law that flags must fall freely (read [Section C of the Respect For The Flag code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/4/8)).

Since the US had only 48 states as recently as 1959, it is likely the courthouse was either built before that year and carried the 48-star flag, or the display piece is meant to reflect US history (much like Confederate flags adorned some southern states court houses until recently).  Either way, it's clear that the flag is just that; a display piece.

Comment: Note for completeness: it is an *unenforceable, unconstitutional* section of the code, so "must" is more like "please do" (and of course the respectful, proper thing to do)

Comment: While I take your points here, this is more supposition and opinion than it is to a why. In Daredevil, the flag is shown quite prominently in the episode as Frank enters the courtroom and several other times while he is on trial. It *feels* more like a statement than something which is just there. If there is a New York statute which says, "All courtrooms will have a 48 star US flag prominently displayed", then I'll take that as an answer. If not, was there anything from the MCU (on/off screen) which denotes why this would be displayed? Seeing the pic from Richard's link makes me wonder more.

Comment: Once a flag, always a flag. Maybe they don't make 48-star flags any more, but if you have a U.S. flag with 48 stars or 15 stars, it's still a perfectly good U.S. flag, and should be treated respectfully according to the flag code. They didn't retire all the old flags every time a new state was admitted.. The number of stars is not a problem; the question we should be asking is why the flag is displayed improperly.

Comment: @user14111: it seems that respect to the flag is lacking in courtrooms: https://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/26/nyregion/in-courtrooms-a-crusade-to-give-the-flag-its-due.html